# How to push the project from azuredevops to visual studio 2019 again?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, tfvc

I push the project from azure to visual studio 2019 through team explorer but it didn't went well because some files are missing. How can I do the same again? The map & get option don't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Open the source control explorer and in the top bar edit the workspace there you can add additional mappings if needed.

Then use the add files and folders option in the toolbar to add the files that are missing from your previous check-in and perform another check-in.

Comment: Thanks man, it really helps ☺️

Comment: If it solved your problem, please mask it as solved/answered.